How to add Payload CMS table to an existing database?
I'm trying to create and admin_users table with PayloadCMS in my NextJS project. I already have a Postgres database running on the cloud with Supabase, with real data.
When I try to run my Payload migration it says I'm about to delete all my other tables, which is something I don't want to do.
What is the correct approach to this?
I couldn't find any answers online.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
